# C# ML.NET Getting an error while training image model from microsoft tutorial

Tags: c#, .net, tensorflow, ml.net

Do you have any ideas on how to fix this problem? Im trying to run project from this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/tutorials/image-classification-api-transfer-learning everything seems okay but when I add the line `ITransformer trainedModel = trainingPipeline.Fit(trainSet);`  It gives me this error: `ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Can't determine the number of source columns without valid data (Parameter 'Source')` Here is gist of my code : https://gist.github.com/kacperospl/cfeecb8a483e0d56b1950df994e00203